# In regards to something taking time 時間がかかる and the connotation that phrase implies

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I wrote the sentence-

> キャンパスからEMXバスに乗れば、ユージンバスターミナルまで１０ぷんぐらいかかります。

However, I was told by my teacher that かかる has a negative connotation and should not be used when explaining an amount of time that is convenient or quick and that I should use something else? As far as I researched, かかる was used in most examples I could find in the textbook or elsewhere. Is this statement about it being negative accurate? and If so would I just say 時間があります or is there another verb I should use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

～まで10分かかります is not necessarily that negative, but it does have the connotation of "require 10 minutes". If you are implying 10 minutes is short enough, you usually have to say something like this:

> バスに乗ればターミナルまで10分で行けます。

If you want to be very neutral, you can also say:

> ここからターミナルまではバスで10分です。

When you want to say "takes **only** 10 minutes" explicitly, you can also say:

> バスに乗ればターミナルまで10分しかかかりません。